# Constrained polymorphism of types

Tags: haskell

I try to define list of constrained polymorphic values, e.g.

```
myList = ["foo", 5] :: [Show a => a]
```

which yields the following error (GHCi, version 8.6.5)

> GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism

Anyways, is it possible to specify a type such that, for example, functions of the form `f :: Show a => [a] -> [String]` could consume a constrained value like above?

In other words, is there a way to verify the following code by the compiler?

```
(++ "fork") . show <$> ["foo", 5]
```

I currently try to test a `Show` type class instance of a GADT by defining a dataset of values and expected results `[(value, "expectedResult")]`. But, due to the fact that GADTs constructors specify the values type, it is not possible to do this naively.

Comment: A list contains elements of the same type. Note that this would not work, since the `show` for `String -> String` is a different one then the `show` for `Int -> String`. So what would the type for `show` be at the left side of `<$>`?

Comment: the type would be `forall a. Show a => [a] -> [String]`, i hoped that maybe with RankNTypes there could be a possibility to make it possible

Comment: You could use an existential type wrapper, but that would lead to `[Wrapper]` which is a complicated type isomorphic to the simpler `[String]`. This is a known anti-pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[Show a => a]` does not mean what you think it does. It's a shorthand for `[∀ a . Show a => a]`, i.e. a list of values *each of which are polymorphic*, not a polymorphic list containing concrete (but unknown) types. That would be an *existential*, `[∃ a . Show a => a]`.

While Haskell doesn't come with anonymous existentials in type expressions, it is possible to obtain them as a declared type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Showable where
  Showable :: Show a => a -> Showable

myList :: [Showable]
myList = [Showable "foo", Showable 5]
```

```
Main*> map (\(Showable x) -> show x ++ "fork") myList 
["\"foo\"fork","5fork"]
```

*however* as chi already commented, there's no point to doing that: all you can possibly do with a Show-constrained existential is to, well, *show it*. I.e., all its information can be captured in a string. Well, then just *store the string* right away!

```
myList :: [String]
myList = [show "foo", show 5]
```

Comment: It's not even 100% true for `Show`, because `showsPrec` does have slightly more information. What you can always do though, even for multi-method classes, is simply store all the methods as partially-applied functions.

Comment: Actually it's `forall a. [Show a => a]` -- it's a *homogenous* list of any type `a` you like, each element of which requires the show instance for `a`. The only value of this type is `[]`, so the `Show` part is completely unnecessary.  OTOH `[Read a => a]` is kind of interesting.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Indeed, that is usually a better (IMO) solution than the existential wrapper. So far, I only found very few cases where I couldn't remove the existential wrapper, e.g. `class C a where { s :: a->a ; z :: a->Bool }` -- here we can not easily pre-apply the value. We could transform `exists a. C a` into the almost-isomorphic `[Bool]`, but that might be less convenient to use.